# XPath select tags by id not descendants of

Tags: xpath

I have the following code and I have to select all the nodes with id="text" but not the nodes that already have a parent with id="text":

```
<fo:block id="text">
  test00
  <fo:block id="text">
      test01
  </fo:block>
  <fo:block>
      test02
  </fo:block>
</fo:block>
<fo:block id="text">
    test03
</fo:block>
```

so in this example the query have to return only the two fo:block with content test00 and test03.

Thank you.

Comment: And what have you written so far?

Comment: Seems invalid (!), no one use the attribute id as "not unique"!  ... In the best case we can say that is not a best practice.

Answer (score 2):

I'd go with something like this:

```
//fo:block[@id='text' and not(./*[@id='text'])]
```

I'm going to give it a test right now to make sure it's sane. Yeah. It returns text00 and text03, as required. So allow me to explain this expression.

```
//fo:block             # Select all fo:block elements in the document
[
  @id='text' and       # Get only those whose id attribute's value is "text"
  not(./*[@id='text']) # and whose children do not have id attributes equal to "text"
]
```

Comment: thank you very much, you were so fast and now you're my new idol!!